# Expected to return a value in arrow function although returned an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

What's wrong with eslint? is this a false positive?

```
const URLParams = search => {
  let hashes = search.slice(search.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')
  let params = {}
  hashes.map(hash => {
      let [key, val] = hash.split('=')
      params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val)
  })

  return params
}
```

Comment: Does `hashes.map` expect a returned value? Since you are using `map` and not `forEach` I would assume it wants you to at least return something from that arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a false positive. It's a misleading error message, but this is not the correct use of `map`.

`map` expects you to return something from the callback function. If you are not building up a new array, you don't need `map`. If you don't return a value from the callback when it's an arrow function, ESLint is presuming that you're making one of the common errors of arrow functions: using a block when you meant an object.

You can use `forEach` here:

```
hashes.forEach(hash => {
  let [key, val] = hash.split('=')
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val)
})
```

Or, and this is preferable in my opinion, just use a normal loop:

```
for (let hash of hashes) {
  let [key, val] = hash.split('=')
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val)
}
```